# How to use threads when retrieving data from database

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

So here is my methods that i am trying to implement with threads however when run it it keeps crashing and i have no idea why.. The logcat doesnt show me the errors as it would when something crashes which leaves me very puzzled..

So basically what im trying to do here is start my activity and while the user is looking at the activty, it starts populating the list in the background, if this helps explain what im trying to accomplish.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        populateExerListView(exercises);
    }
};

public void loadDataFromDatabase(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            exercises = dbh.getAllExercises(bodypart_chosen);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

public void populateExerListView(final ArrayList<AdapterExercisesList.Exercise> exercises){

    ListAdapter edsAdapter = new AdapterExercisesList(this, exercises);
    exerciseListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseListView);

    exerciseListView.setAdapter(edsAdapter);

    exerciseListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    int pos = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    //gets the bodypart by passing in the pos
                    String exercise_chosen = exercises.get(pos).get_exerciseName();

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                    exerciseClicked(exercise_chosen, formattedDate);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: how do you know that the app crashes if logcat does not show anything about it

Comment: and you miss closing brace for your `loadDataFromDatabase` method. anyhow see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

you define runnable but you never pass it to thread,

you need to change this:

```
public void loadDataFromDatabase(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            exercises = dbh.getAllExercises(bodypart_chosen);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
```

to this:

```
public void loadDataFromDatabase(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            exercises = dbh.getAllExercises(bodypart_chosen);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();

}//end method
```

Comment: argh... I thought this was going to be it. Almost fixed it? Hmmm how do i explain this... when i try to populate my list for the first time it works just fine, but after it is populated and when I click the back button and attempt to click the listview again. It crashes on my emulator, it says unfortunately "App Name" has stopped. However when i look at my logcat i do not see any red lines

Comment: probably there is an error message filtering enabled in logcat. you need to disable it so that you can see error messages. set filter to "all"

Comment: i set it to "no filters" and i still do not see it.. :(

Comment: by the way, why do you use `int pos` variable ? you should use `int position` variable from the argument list of `onItemClick`

Comment: ah good point, that was from something similar i did where i just copied the stuff and forgot to take that one out